# How to change the position of on of the Grouped columns in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I was creating an SSRS report show customer ledger. I wanted to merge the cells of Date, Mode and Balance columns for same dates. I did it using the row grouping. Screenshots are given below.

#### Design View

[image: Design View]

#### Report Preview

[image: Report Preview]

But I couldn't change the **position of 'Balance'** column to the **right end** as Customer requested. Is there any way to reposition it to the right ?

Comment: Do you mean you want Balance after Debit? What column are you grouping on?

Comment: @Harry Yes, I want Balance after Debit column. I am grouping on Date column

Answer (score 0):

After the debit column insert a column. Insert an expression in the following format: =RunningValue(Fields!Credit.Value,SUM,"Tablix1") - RunningValue(Fields!Debit.Value,SUM,"Tablix1").